# Lifting the projective property through the affine centre

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be an algebraically closed field. There are many interesting examples of $\mathbb{k}$-algebras $R$ which admit a large central subalgebra $Z_0$ such that $R$ is a free $Z_0$-module and $Z_0$ is an affine $\mathbb{k}$-algebra. For instance, this is the case if we consider the universal enveloping algebra of a restricted Lie algebra when $\mathbb{k}$ has characteristic $p > 0$. Other examples arise when $\mathbb{k}$ has any characteristic and the generators of $R$ exhibit quantum commutation relation with quantum parameter a root of unity, a typical example being the quantised coordinate ring on affine space. A good reference for the theory of such algebras is ``Lectures on Quantum groups'' by Brown and Goodearl, especially part 3.

My question is about the representation theory of such rings. Here's the setup: take $\mathbb{k}$ and $Z_0 \subseteq R$ as above, and suppose that $M$ is a left $R$-module. Suppose also that for every maximal ideal $I\unlhd Z_0$ and every integer $k > 0$ we know that $M/I^k M$ is a projective $R/I^k R$-module. Does it follow that $M$ is projective over $R$?

I've been poring over Bourbaki to no avail but I think the question is sufficiently simple that, if the answer is positive, then it will probably be well-known. I'd be very grateful for a proof, reference, counterexample or a comment. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not.  Take $R=\mathbb{k}[x]$ and $Z_0 = R$.  Any maximal ideal of $Z_0$ has the form $I=(x-a)$, with $a\in \mathbb{k}$, since $\mathbb{k}$ is algebraically closed.

Take $M=\mathbb{k}[[x]]$.  If $I=(x-a)$, with $a\neq 0$, then $I^k M = M$ for any $k>0$, since $(x-a)^k$ is invertible in $\mathbb{k}[[x]]$.  Hence $M/I^k M = 0$, and is thus trivially a projective $R/I^kR$-module.

Now, assume that $a=0$.  Then $M/I^k M = \mathbb{k}[[x]]/(x^k) = \mathbb{k}[x]/(x^k) = R/I^k R$ is also projective over $R/I^k R$ for any $k>0$.

On the other hand, $M$ is not a projective $R$-module.  Indeed, in this case projective is equivalent to free, and if $F$ is any free $R$-module, then $(x-1)F\neq F$; however, $(x-1)M = M$.